# Django: How to display context data from one template on multiple templates

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have to use the context update method in every view in order to show data from my sidebar.html template that I include in other templates as part of my navigation. Is there another way in which I can include the data from my sidebar.html other templates as well? I'm going to have to do this for a lot of templates and does not seem like the right way to do it.

## blog/views.py

```
class BlogPostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = BlogPost
    context_object_name = "post"
    template_name = "blog/single.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogPostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(
            {
                "categories": Category.objects.all().annotate(
                    post_count=Count("categories")
                )
            },
        )

        return context
```

## Core/views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    context_object_name = "posts"
    template_name = "core/index.html"
    paginate_by = 4
    ordering = ["-date_posted"]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(
            {
                "categories": Category.objects.all().annotate(
                    post_count=Count("categories")
                )
            },
        )

        return context
```

## core/includes/sidebar.html

```html
...
<div class="sidebar-box ftco-animate">
    <h3 class="sidebar-heading">Categories</h3>
    <ul class="categories">
        {% for category in categories %}
        <li><a href="#">{{ category.title }}
                <span>({{ category.post_count }})</span></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use djangos context processor for that using that you can get that data in all the template base without passing the context in all the template

for example i want site settings it includes settings of site like contactus and emailaddress all of that column so i will make a context processor for that

make new file

context_processor.py

in that

```
from foo import Configuration

def code_base(request):

    conf = Configuration.objects.all()
    return {'conf':conf}

Note: also add that context processor in the settings.py under templates on the context processor list
```

so from now on you dont have to pass 'conf' in all template as context you can directly access the {{ conf }} without passing context in template